# Rolling file appender properties

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Why does log4j rolling file appender continue to write logs to same file even after setting `MaxFileSize`?

It only creates a new log file at server restart. Why?

```
# Root logger option 
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout 
# Direct log messages to a log file 
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.file.File=file_path 
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=500MB 
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n # Direct log messages to stdout 
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out 
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Please share your Logging properties or xml configs.

Comment: Done edited. You can see.

Comment: can you include this line and see if it works: 

log4j.appender.file.append=true
log4j.appender.file.threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.file.immediateFlush=true

Comment: @NKR : `appender.file.append=true` will append the logs to same file even after restart

try with false. because same cofiguration is working perfectly fine for me.
`log4j.appender.file.Append=false`

Comment: So by default in log4j is it true?

Comment: Bro adding these still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below configuration for log4J.

[image]

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.file.Append=false
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/LogFolder/myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```